# SQL get most hits on specified datetime period

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

Need help of making a SQL query which would give me rowcount on simultaneous logged in users in specified period (like last week, or last month). I need to get the date and count.

SQL table has these columns:
ID(indentifier, numeric)
Username(varchar)
LoggedInDate(datetime)
LoggedOutDate(datetime)

Idea is to get count of max number of users who are logged in same time in given period.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Eero

Comment: Please be more specific about the "rowcount on simultaneous logged in users". Does this counter the maximum number of users at any specific moment in the time period, or the total number of logged in users in that period, or the average count of users in the given period?

Comment: Every time user logs in, new row is made with UserName and LoggedInDate. And when user logs out, row is updated with LoggedOutDate. I want to get count of maximun users(rows) who are logged in same time (between LoggedInDate and LoggedOutDate). Lets say the period is month, so i want to know the date when there were most logged in users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The max must have occured when someone logged in so we check how many was logged in after each login

```
SELECT MAX(LoggedInCount)
FROM table
     CROSS APPLY (
          SELECT COUNT(1) AS LoggedInCount
          FROM table AS InnerTable
          WHERE InnerTable.LoggedInDate <= table.LoggedInDate
                AND InnerTable.LoggedOutDate >= table.LoggedInDate
     ) AS CA1
WHERE table.LoggedInDate IN YourPeriod
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(1) as counter, 
DATE_FORMAT(LoggedInDate, '%Y-%m-%d') as loggedInDate 
from tabel 
group by DATE_FORMAT(LoggedInDate, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Something similar to that Id say
Then you get x amount users logged in on z day, you can increase the date format to include hours if needs be